# Using regexmatch to match part of a cell to values in a column to see there is a match

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column (Column A) of cells with tracking information.  Each cell contains the date shipped and a tracking number.  I have another column (Column B) with a bunch of tracking numbers.  How can I see if the tracking number in column B match any of the tracking numbers in Column A?

This is what I have tried:

```
=IF(RegExMatch(A1, TO_TEXT(B:B)),"YES","NO") but that's not working
```

All of the results are coming back as "YES" even though there is no match.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Show sample screenshot or sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YnFNU9MFlQg8mW6bqmQboa6lUVvZiwvEEoINFgxUt1I/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B:B), IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""&B:B, 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B:B))), 1, 0))<>"", "YES", "NO"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain the formula to me? I thought I was decent at formula writing but I am having a tough time following what's going on here.  Thanks!

Comment: sure. we `TEXTJOIN` B column like `83162|93692|67040|etc` then we `REGEXEXTRACT` every found value from this textjoin-string from column A. if we stop here then `YES` would be on C1 coz match is in A1. therefore we need `VLOOKUP` so that `YES` would appear in C6 next to B6. and that's kinda it. `IFERROR` for killing errors. 2nd `IF` for outputting `YES` / `NO`. 1st `IF` with `LEN` for stopping `ARRAYFORMULA` at row 9 coz row 10 is empty.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense to me.  One more question, what if columns A and B are of different lengths? What if column A has 12 entries but column B has 10 entries? The formula doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added more tracking numbers to column A but I am getting a No in column C even when the tracking number appears in column B.  Trying to grasp this formula but still having some trouble it looks like.